# How can I redirect/handle chrome traffic with chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I'd like to create chrome extension which behaves like a proxy, so I can do whatever I want with HTTP requrests coming from browser. What approach can I use for this? What API to use for HTTP request hooking? Googling and reading chrome documentation didn't give me any ideas.

Thanx.

Comment: And what's wrong with [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)?

Comment: in addition to the above post [chrome.proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy) maybe useful for you. Also see list [JavaScript APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)

Comment: @wOxxOm, tons of thanx for webRequest, this looks like what I need